# Overriding FOSUserBundle Login Form

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

Im following the documentation here:https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/overriding_templates.rst

I chose to Create A Child Bundle And Override Template so in my bundle I have

```
class MyBundle extends Bundle
{
    //declare bundle as a child of the FOSUserBundle so we can override the parent bundle's templates
    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'FOSUserBundle';
    }

}
```

In my bundle I have added the following files

```
MyBundle
      \Resources
               \views
                     \Security
                      login.html.twig
```

Matching the FOS bundle structure as mentioned in the documentation

login.html.twig

```
{% extends 'AnotherBundle::layout.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}Log In{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    {% block fos_user_content %}{% endblock %}
{% endblock %}
```

When I go to the login page my header loads fine but there's no login form, what am doing wrong?

Comment: If someone hits this: the documentation is not located at https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/overriding_templates.html.

Comment: You can find 2 detailed examples [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48138063/5356216)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Because you didn't write the code that render the login form.

open `/vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/FOS/UserBundle/Resources/views/Security/login.html.twig`, copy the code in the `fos_user_content` block to your custom `login.html.twig`, reload the page, then you'll see the form.

If you want to customize the form, rewrite the code you've copied.

Comment: Thanks, that was the issue. I also override the layout file MyBundle\Resources\view\layout.html.twig and extend my base layout so I get my theme loaded as well

Answer (score -3):

When you have nested blocks you need to tell explicitly which block you're closing. So, try this:

```
{% block content %}
    {% block fos_user_content %}{% endblock fos_user_content %}
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: Not needed, twig know wich block must close